# Can't upload file to App Engine "list index out of range"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cordova

I am trying to updload a picture from a Phonegap application to my Python App Engine project.  The phone app trys to upload the file but App engine returns a "list index out of range" error.

I have the following code on the App Engine side to handle the files,

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
    upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')    
    blob_info = upload_files[0]        
    self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())
```

And the following code on the PhoneGap side to send the file,

```
    function uploadImage() {
        var smallImage = document.getElementById('cameraImage');
        if (smallImage.src && smallImage.src !== "") {
            var f = new FileTransfer();
            f.upload(smallImage.src, "http://testtest.appspot.com/upload",
                // success callback
                function(result) {
                    document.getElementById('uploadProgress').innerHTML =
                        result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent';
                    alert(result.responseCode + ": " + result.response);
                },
                // error callback
                function(error) {
                    alert('error uploading file: ' + error.code);
                },
                // options
                { fileName: 'myImage.jpg', 
                  params: { 'username':'jtyberg' } 
                });
        }
    }
```

The error is as follows,

```
"POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 500 487 - "BlackBerry9550/5.0.0.469 Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/-1" "testtest.appspot.com" ms=416 cpu_ms=93 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.014221 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117ca6c4ea405471eea592a8f79ac6
E 2011-08-06 11:49:17.309
list index out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 702, in __call__
        handler.post(*groups)
    File "/base/data/home/apps/s~testtest/1.352363227571120815/main.py", line 62, in post
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When I try to upload a file via a web form it works great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to generate the upload url via `blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')`. Right now you are making a multi-part POST directly your upload handler url.  The intermediate url is critical because it generates a Blobstore key and adds it to the MIME header before passing it to the handler.

Comment: It looks to me like it's not being uploaded as part of a multipart form, either, but rather as the raw payload of the request.

Comment: Based on the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) it seems like the FileTransfer object creates a multi-part post.

Comment: Odd. There's no field name specified anywhere.

Comment: Great, that worked!  Still learning more as to how create_upload_url works.  I'm assuming I will have to somehow request a new url via javascript every time I upload a file?

Comment: Glad it worked!  You are correct - you'll need a new url for each upload.  Watch out for stale upload urls (which can happen if a user uses the 'back' button or is inactive for a while), it's best to generate the url immediately before you'll need it.

Comment: To prevent the extra request to obtain the blob_url everytime you upload the file, you can use urlfetch to POST to the blob_url directly from server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about PhoneGap (what is it?) but that Python code is expecting your file to be sent via HTTP POST attached to a field named `file`. Presumably, PhoneGap isn't sending it against that field.