# What causes a list index out of range here?

Tags: python, forms, http, google-app-engine, blob

I've had some problems with handling forms and getting back to basics after an upgrade I can't get the minimal example to work:

```
class PhotoUploadFormHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self): 
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        self.response.out.write('<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' % blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload_photo'))
        self.response.out.write('''Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br> <input type="submit"
            name="submit" value="Submit"> </form></body></html>''')

class PhotoUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        try:
            upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
            user_photo = UserPhoto(user=users.get_current_user(),
                                   blob_key=upload.key())
            db.put(user_photo)
            self.redirect('/view_photo/%s' % upload.key())

        except Exception, ex:
            self.response.out.write(str(ex))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([    

('/upload_form', PhotoUploadFormHandler),
                                      ('/upload_photo', PhotoUploadHandler),
```

The above return the exception at accessing the uploaded file:

> list index out of range

Why?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please include the complete stacktrace, rather than editing out all the useful details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that *get_uploads* is returning an empty list.  Accordingly, the `[0]` fails.

Comment: Yes I understand but not why a simple upgrade from python 2.6 to python 2.7 caused it. If I use the form to upload a file then I get an error and with python 2.6 the code works.

Comment: There is not sufficient information in the post to diagnose the root of the problem.  It would help to post the traceback and to generate a log message showing what was returned by *get_uploads*.

Comment: Thank @Raymond Hettinger it seems the problem I have is "too localized" and I clean new deployment doesn't cause this error. So I will either research and post more about this question or consider it a too localized question where I managed to paint myself into a corner combining component that can't do what I want.

Comment: did you get to the bottom of this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @Awalias make sure your form includes `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. This is one thing that causes this error.

Comment: @RobertDodd .. is there another thing? I'm having this too.

Comment: @OllieFord .. Make sure you are generating an upload url each time: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6989460/306503